# Asking help with Taylor approximation of expectation of ratio

Tags: mathematical-statistics, ratio, expected-value, taylor-series

I am trying to understand how I should approach the problem of a Taylor approximation to the expectation of the ratio of two random variables. In my particular problem I am concerned with the following ratio estimated using a sample of size $n$

$$\hat{\gamma_i}=\frac{x_i\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}=\frac{x_i\bar{y}}{\bar{x}}$$

We may assume for simplicity $E(x_i)=\mu_x$ and $E(y_i)=\mu_y$, but we may not have $E(x_iy_i) \ne E(x_i)E(y_i)$.

I try to find $E(\hat{\gamma})$. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You should check out http://web.stanford.edu/class/cme308/OldWebsite/notes/TaylorAppDeltaMethod.pdf.  It has a similar problem (a ratio) that is worked out.

Comment: Are the $y_i$'s independent of the $x_i$'s?

Comment: Something seems strange about that material. I do not think it is legitimate (i.e. precise enough) to make a first order Taylor approximation to a ratio of two random variables. As discussed in that document, this is, namely, simply the ratio of expectations. I am looking for a second or third order approximation of my ratio.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos No, not necessarily, $E(x_i y_i) \ne E(x_i)E(y_i)$.

Comment: This seems helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables

Comment: The ratio might not have an expectation at all.  For instance, when the $x_i$ are independent of the $y_i$ and $x_i/\bar x$ has nonzero density at $0$, $\gamma$ will not have an expectation.  Thus, investigating this issue should be one of the very first considerations, to be carried out before attempting any kind of approximation. What can you say about the joint distribution of $(x_i, \bar x, \bar y)$ in this regard?

Comment: When summed over all $i$ estimator $\gamma$ is known as a ratio estimator. Generally it is assumed $x$ and $y$ have some kind of relationship, thus are not independent. Also I should say $\mu_x \ne 0$, so that $x$ and $y$ are scaled in a way that identifies $\gamma$. I am trying to approximate the bias of the ratio estimator of the population total of $x$. Does this help?

Comment: Yes; I had guessed it might be something like that.  But details matter. For example, I am also guessing that the support of $x$ is strictly positive.  I also wonder whether you need to assume that $x$ is a random variable--often its values are considered fixed by the experimenter.  If not, then the issue arises concerning how to model its random variations. I am also curious about the form of $\hat\gamma_i$: if you are trying to predict a value of $y$ when $x$ is $x_i$, then the $x_i$ in the numerator should not be considered random at all!

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty in your expression comes from the $1/\bar{x}$ term, which is the term we will need to expand.

$$ \frac{1}{\bar{x}} = \frac{1}{E(\bar{x})+\bar{x}-E(\bar{x})}$$

$$ \frac{1}{\bar{x}} = \frac{1}{E(\bar{x})} - \frac{\bar{x}-E(\bar{x})}{E(\bar{x})^2} + \dots $$

So, for example, we find that:

$$ E(\frac{1}{\bar{x}}) \approx \frac{1}{E(\bar{x})} - 0 + \frac{var(\bar{x})}{E(\bar{x})^3} $$

Your case is more complex because you also have $x_i \bar{y}$ but you should be able to finish from there

Comment: In the question, the OP verifies that we cannot assume the $y_i$ are independent of the $x_i$. That assumption, however, seems to be the basis of your focus on $1/\bar x$ alone.

Comment: The 2nd order Taylor expension for a ratio with two dependent random variables is given here. The difficulty is in writing it out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables